# Реализация массива в обратном порядке

Tags: java

Вчера в задание надо было создать массив который выводил бы данные в обратном порядке.

Сделал не массив а

```
// Обьявляем строку и присваиваем ей значение
String str1 = " Football ";

// Преобразуем строку str1 в массив символов
char[] reverseName = str1.toCharArray();

for (int i = reverseName.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
    System.out.print(reverseName[i]);
}
```

Так я научился возвращать String в обратном порядке. Как сделать если это массив:

```
String[] str2 = [10];
```

Как вывести я понял строки, но как сделать чтобы они приняли обратный порядок не знаю?

Вчера пробовал этим же путем и вроде получилось, но по большому счету методом тыка.

```
for (int i = str2.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    Sout(str2[i])
};
```

Вопрос что происходит при этих строках вообще и почему `(str.lenght-1)` и `(i--);`?

Сложно задал простой вопрос. Ну как мог.

Answer (score 1):

Массив содержит элементы к которым можно получить доступ по индексу (номеру позиции элемента в массиве данных). В С-подобных языка, в частности Java, индексация начинается с 0, то есть первый элемент имеет индекс 0. Соответственно, так как элементов в массиве length, то индекс последнего элемента равен length-1 (индекс первого 0, последнего length-1, а всего элементов length).

Теперь рассмотрим код:

```
for (
     // Идем с хвоста массива данных. Задаем начальное значение индекса
     int i = str2.length-1;
     // Цикл работает пока индекс не перескочит "голову" массива
     i >= 0;
     // Единичный шаг от элемента к элементу. "От хвоста" к "голове"
     i--
) {
     // Выводим значение массива, которому соответствует текущее
     // значение индекса (номера позиции в массиве)
     System.out.println(str2[i]);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Что происходит в строках

```
for (int i = str2.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    Sout(str2[i])
};
```

Нетрудно понять, что это цикл `for` с переменной, которая берет значение последнего элемента массива и декрементирует её до первого элемента при каждой итерации. То есть происходит обход элементов массива по индексу в обратном порядке.

Answer (score 1):

Выводим массив в обратном порядке на стримах:

```
String[] strArr = new String[] {"слово", "два слова", "еще три слова"};

Stream.of(strArr)
      .sorted((o1, o2) -> -1)
      .forEach(System.out::println);

// еще три слова
// два слова
// слово
```

см. enSO: [Java 8 stream reverse order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24010109/8280225)

Answer (score 0):

как вариант можно так сделать еще

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Массив слов
    String[] words = {"one", "two", "three"};
    //Кидаем в лист
    List arr = Arrays.asList(words);
    //Через  колекшн разворачиваем
    Collections.reverse(arr);

}
```